# Why is the inline formset not validating

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, inline-formset

I have two models with foreign key relation

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Project(models.Model):
    STATUSES = (
        ('Ongoing', 'Ongoing'),
        ('Completed', 'Completed')
    )

    YEARS = (
        (2019, 2019),
        (2020, 2020),
        (2021, 2021),
        (2022, 2022)
    )
    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    client = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    year = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=YEARS)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUSES)
    picture = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Photo(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey("Project", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="images", blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    slide = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I want photos and project to be created on the same form so I've used inline_formset_factory

forms.py

```
from django.forms import inlineformset_factory
from projects.models import Photo, Project
from django.forms import ModelForm


class ProjectModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = (
            'name',
            'client',
            'year',
            'picture',
            'status',
            'description',
        )


class PhotoModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = (
            'image',
            'slide',
            'description'
        )


PhotoFormset = inlineformset_factory(Project, Photo, form=PhotoModelForm, extra=1)
```

I used the generic CreateView

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from projects.forms import PhotoFormset, ProjectModelForm
from django.shortcuts import redirect, reverse, render
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from .models import Photo, Project

# Create your views here.
class ProjectCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'projects/project_create.html'
    form_class = ProjectModelForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProjectCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['photos_formset'] = PhotoFormset()
        return context
    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = None
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        photo_formset = PhotoFormset(self.request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and photo_formset.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form, photo_formset)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form, photo_formset)
    
    def form_valid(self, form, photo_formset):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.save()
        print('valid')
        photos = photo_formset.save(commit=False)
        for photo in photos:
            photo.project = self.object
            photo.save()
        return reverse('projects:projectspage')

    def form_invalid(self, form, photo_formset):
        if not photo_formset.is_valid():
            print('invalid formset')
        return self.render_to_response(
            self.get_context_data(form=form, photos_formset=photo_formset)
        )

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('projects:projectspage')
```

this is the template

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_filters %}
<!-- crispy_forms_tags -->

{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
        <h2>create new project</h2>
        <form method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form|crispy }}
            <h2 class="display-6 my-5">
                Add photos
            </h2>
            {{ photos_formset.as_p }}
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary">
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

When I submit form_invalid is returned from the post method of the view

How do i get the inline_formset to validate or is there better way of doing it

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to write those views as functions, seems more straightforward, try:

```
@login_required
def post_news(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        project_form = ProjectModelForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        photo_form = PhotoModelForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        picture = request.FILES['picture']
        image = request.FILES['image']
        if project_form.is_valid() and photo_form.is_valid():
            project_instance = project_form.save(commit=False)
            project_instance.picture = picture
            project_instance.save()
            photo_instance = project_form.save(commit=False)
            photo_instance.project = project_instance
            photo_instance.image = image
            photo_instance.save()                

            return reverse('projects:projectspage')
else:
    project_form = ProjectModelForm()
    photo_form = PhotoModelForm()

return render(request, 'projects/project_create.html',
              {'project_form': project_form, 'photo_form': photo_form})
```

You will have to account for a case when no picture for the project model is is provided I think. Just pop both forms into your template and this should work.

Comment: i get a MultiValueDictKeyError at /projects/create/
'picture'

Comment: Right, you need to have enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form tag in the template file.

Comment: Great images are now in the post but I get an attribute error,. 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: Please edit your post and add the whole error traceback.